# How to match Paypal user that triggered transaction (frontend) to IPN (backend)?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, paypal-ipn

I'm using Paypal hosted buttons to trigger payments and then receiving the IPN on a Google Cloud function like this.

```
exports.ipn = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
   var reqBody = req.body;
   let reqPaymentDate = reqBody.payment_date;
   admin.database().ref('transactions/' + reqPaymentDate).set(reqBody);
   res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

The body of the message doesn't allow me to know which one of my Firebase registered users triggered the Transaction. This function is triggered by http so the firebase context is undefined.

Is there a way to know which user triggered the payment under these circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

On the hosted button type

```
<input name="custom" value="<yourUserId>" type="hidden">
```

The IPN will then contain  field named custom with your User Id